# Слово "борщ"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а от какого корня происходит всем известное слово "борщ"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово **борщ** заимствовано в 19 в. из украинского языка, где **борщ** - это суп из свеклы с капустой (суп из борщевника). Словом **борщ** (борщевник) называли съедобное растение с острыми листьями (от слова **бор** - хвоя, то, что колет; потом словом **бор** стали называть хвойное дерево, сосну, а позже хвойный лес)

Comment: Никак не позже XVI века.

*В России упоминается в памятниках 16в17 вв. [1]. Очерки о нём можно встретить в новгородских ямских книгах за 1586в1631 гг[8]. Также в XVI веке борщ настойчиво рекомендует Домострой[6]. *

http://www.enci.ru/%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89

Впрочем, даже заимствование из украинского не общепризнано.
Но в главном - согласен.